# assign value to gurobi variable

Tags: c#, gurobi

I want to make a branch and bound from my problem in Gurobi with C#. If the value of `y[m]` is not binary, then branch value of every `y[m]` to 0 and 1 as an additional constraint. Here is the definition of `y[m]` and my code:

```
GRBVar[] y = new GRBVar[M];
for (int m = 0; m < y.Length; m++)
{
 y[m] = master.AddVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.CONTINUOUS, "y" + m);
}
if (objectivevalue == master.ObjVal)
y[1].Set(GRB.DoubleAttr.X, 1.0);
```

This code said

> error code 10004, error at GRBVar.Set.

I think It must be from the new set value of y, but I don't know what's the correct syntax.

Comment: Are you trying to write your own branch-and-bound code? Or are you trying to direct the Gurobi MIP search?

Comment: @GregGlockner I want to do branch and price, so I have to write my branch and bound and column generation by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The X attribute is read-only.  To fix a variable, set both bounds (the UB/LB attributes).

Comment: Will it introduce additional overhead to the solver? In other words, is the variable fixing operation done when constructing linear expressions or presolving the model?

Comment: Fixing a variable adds no significant overhead.